# Applying aggregating function with spark streaming scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, aggregation

I need to apply an aggregation function on a stream of data with apache spark streaming  (NO APACHE SPARK STREAMING SQL).

In my case I have a kafka producer tha send messages in JSON format.
The format is `{'a': String, 'b': String, 'c': Integer, 'd': Double}`

I need to aggregate on attributes `'a'` and `'b'` every 5 Seconds and I have to apply an aggregation function on the other 2 attributes (e.g. Average, or Sum, or Min, or Max).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried the `reduce` function? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams

Comment: the problem is that the reduce function take 2 parameters and return 1. I need to have the same schema. I other words if my initial schema is `{'a': String, 'b': String, 'c': Integer, 'd': Double}`the resulting schema (with an AVG aggregate function) should be `{'GROUPBYa': String, 'GROUPBYb': String, 'AVGc': Integer, 'AVGd': Double}`

Comment: you could also use `transform` or `foreachRDD` and apply any arbitrary RDD function, or convert to Dataframes and use the dataframes aggregation API

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, you could approach aggregation like this:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

jsonDstream.foreachRDD{jsonRDD => 
  val df = sparkSession.read.json(jsonRDD)
  val aggr = df.groupBy($"a", $"b").agg(avg($"c"))
  ... do something with aggr ...
}
```